# Attaching a parameter to each GET Request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Looking to see if there is an elegant solution for adding a parameter to each GET request based upon a session value in a Rails app. (4.2.6 if needed)

Example:

- We have a session variable `session[:test] = 123`
- User makes request to example.com/random_path
- We'd like the request to always append the param `"?test=#{session[:test]}"`
- So the user would be routed to example.com/random_path?test=123

Love to hear any ideas on this - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the generated URLs to that path to always have a certain parameter in them when they are generated, you can write your own `url_for` or `link_to` helper for that specific route, or override `default_url_options` and set this parameter if the action or controller name match some condition:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options(options = {})
    if controller_name == 'my_controller'
      options[:test] = session[:test]
    end

    options
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Would [redirect_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to_) be a solution? See the code below:

> redirected_url = "https://foo.com?test=#{session[:test]}"
>
> redirect_to redirected_url

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

The routes can be generated as:

```
random_path(random, test: session[:test])
```

It will redirect to:

```
example.com/random_path?test=123
```

where test = session[:test]